# getElementById(child_div_id) VS $(parentDiv).attr("child_div")

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

I have lots of different Div elements displayed on the page.
Some of them have some relationships between each other: e.g. one is appended on another.

I need to add, remove and update many of them dinamycally,
so to access them any time, I have thought of two options:

give each div unique ID and then do `getElementById` when I need it,

or, give as few ID's as possible and access child divs by their parent. for this I have to do something like this:

```
$(parentDiv).attr("child", childDiv), or $(parentDiv).data("child", childDiv)"
```

and get child elements with:

```
$(parentDiv).attr("child"), or $(parentDiv).data("child")
```

my question is, which is more efficient way (which is faster, which is considered as a better design, so on..).

Comment: *"getElementById(child_div_id) VS $(parentDiv).attr(“child_div”)"* Those do completely different things.

Comment: could you more carefully read my post, please?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think the intention here is to either have IDs on every element or a manual relationship by listing the children of a div as its attributes.

Comment: @Nodarius: Could you more carefully read my comment, please?

Comment: @BrendanBullen: But that doesn't reduce the number of IDs, which is what those lines are introduced as being for. Putting the child IDs on the parent elements as attributes still requires the child elements to have IDs.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Very true. It was just a clarification rather than a justification. @Nodarius As you can probably tell from the feedback, this is not what the `attr` and `data` functions are for. You probably could get a functioning algorithm to navigate your DIVs using the `attr` and `data` functions as reference lookups but in the end it would most likely be wildly inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or, give as few ID's as possible and access child divs by their parent. for this I have to do something like this: $(parentDiv).attr("child", childDiv), or $(parentDiv).data("child", childDiv)"
>
> and get child elements with - $(parentDiv).attr("child"), or $(parentDiv).data("child")

That's not how you access child or descendant elements. You use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children), [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find), etc.

> my question is, which is more efficient way (which is faster, which is considered as a better design, so on..).

Those are probably separate questions. You're unlikely to get much more efficient access to an element than by an `id`, but the difference in efficiency between that and finding it structurally isn't likely to be *significant* if your structure is sound. A few anchor points from which you can navigate should be sufficient.

It's hard to provide a solid example without more information about your structure, but let's consider the fairly classic case of a table where you want to respond to clicks on cells:

```
<table>
<tbody id="foo">
<tr data-info="first row">
<td>One</td>
<td>Two</td>
<td>Three</td>
</tr>
<tr data-info="second row">
<td>One</td>
<td>Two</td>
<td>Three</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

It's fairly common to want to update cells based on clicks on other cells. You can do that by using the table's ID, event delegation, and structural traversal methods.

```
$("#foo").on('click', 'td', function() {
    // `this` is the cell that was clicked. If I want row-level data, I'd use:
    alert("This row's info is " + $(this).closest('tr').data('info'));

    // Or maybe I want the last cell in the row
    alert("Last cell's text: " + $(this).siblings().last().text());
});
```

Comment: Dear T.J, thank you for your great response, but my main point was: "have IDs on every element or a manual relationships by listing the children or(child_type1, child_type2, so on..) of a div as its attributes? more detailed explanation -  I have 7 main columns as days,(like Calendar) with unique ID's, and on each DayColumn I have several different types of Divs each of which is only 1 on each DayColumn. they are - DayHeader, DayBody, DayBusyTime (maybe some more). should I give each of them unique ID's or should I do - $(DayColumn).data("dayHeader", DayHeader)"?

Comment: @Nodarius: Ah, I see what you're saying. I'd probably give them classes and then refer to them via `$(DayColumn).find(".dayHeader")` unless they're not children. If they aren't children, sure, no harm in using `data` (not `attr`) to build the relationships although that can only be done in code rather than in markup.

Answer (score 0):

For the better design approach, try to avoid creating dynamic elements with ids.  It's usually far more simple and (much easier to debug) if you are just creating css classes as required for dynamically added elements.

If you create your id's dynamically, you always have to ensure that the given id is unique on the page and this will lead to complexity on non trivial pages.  In addition to this, IE and Chrome treat non unique ids differently (also depending on browser version) which makes it very frustrating to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Give the elements a class name, this way you can group the elements together and then you can use jQuery to access them directly. So anything under parent1 give a parent1 class etc

```
 $('.parent1').remove();  // will remove all parent1 classes
```